# Nginx Simple Redirect URL

Tags: nginx, redirect

From URL:

```
test.com/watch?v=y3vmIa_gh1
```

To URL:

```
test.com/dl/y3vmIa_gh1
```

How can I transfer the url permanently. Thanks Very Much!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add this directive to your nginx configuration file (under /etc/nginx/sites-available/, within the "server" block:

```
rewrite ^/dl/(your-regex-here)$ /watch?v=$1 last;
```

**your-regex-here** would be a regular expression that matches the kind of expression you are trying to capture (you must leave parentheses around it to capture it).

From the question, it's unclear what kind of expression you need to capture. It looks like it could be a base 64, URL safe string.

sources: https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/

Comment: How do I fix this 
`location /dl {
  rewrite ^/dl/(.*)$ /view.php?v=$1;
}

rewrite ^/dl/(.*)$ /watch?v=$1 last;`

I use your code still not working